# Searching XML String in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need a way to search through an XML String and return an array containing the "record" elements that meet multiple search criteria.

The structure is this:

```
  <record>
     <project_name>Deploy Document Management</project_name>
     <project_phase>Design</porject_phase>
     <status>Not Started</status>
     <priority>Medium</priority>
  </record>
  <record>
     <project_name>Do Something Else</project_name>
     <project_phase>Design</porject_phase>
     <status>Not Started</status>
     <priority>Medium</priority>   
  </record>
```

If I wanted to return an array of "records" where status="Not Started" and priority = "Medium".... how would I do so using javascript or JQuery?

To be clear, I need the whole record for each record that matches the criteria.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start would be to parse the XML, for example with [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

You can then acces the DOM of the returned document as you usually would

Example:

```js
var xml = '<xml><record><project_name>Deploy Document Management</project_name><project_phase>Design</project_phase><status>Not Started</status><priority>Medium</priority></record><record><project_name>Do Something Else</project_name><project_phase>Design</project_phase><status>Not Started</status><priority>Low</priority></record></xml>'

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
var $xml = $(xmlDoc)
var $records = $xml.find("record").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find("status").text() == "Not Started" && 
    $(this).find("priority").text() == "Medium"
});

// $records already holds all Elements as an Array, but you cold get the texts like this:
var records = []
$records.each(function() {
  // do your thing
  records.push($(this).text())
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(records))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you have a typo in your original XML `project_phase`

Comment: Perfect... exactly what I was looking for.